# Pig Script: Find sum of items in a group

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

This is the line I am trying to run

`counts = FOREACH z {sum=SUM(B::counter);GENERATE group as A::month,sum;};`

However I am getting the following error:

```
<file s3://emr-test/kiran/script/goal.pig, line 6, column 28> Invalid field projection. Projected field [B::counter] does not exist in schema: group:chararray,y:bag{:tuple(A::id:chararray,A::month:chararray,B::counter:int)}.
```

How to do sum aggregation on such a schema which has bag of tuples grouped based on one column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if this is what you are looking for:

- dump A;
  (a,b,1)
  (a,b,3)
  dump B;
       (a,b)
        C = JOIN A by $1 , B by $1;
        D = GROUP C by $1;
          E = FOREACH D GENERATE FLATTEN(A.$0),group,SUM(C.A::num);
           dump E;

Answer (score 1):

SUM function works on bag of tuples where tuple contain value of int,float etc .But here , bag contains tuple of tuple. If you need to perform any aggregation , in that case you have to write an UDF where you can pass the bag and parse through the members to find the sum.Or you have to restructure the data in such a way that it contains a bag of counter  here

Comment: I have one table with structure (a,b,int) and another with (a,b). I want to do a join of both and sum all ints belonging to groups of b. The problem is that after a join I end up with this tuple of tuple form, please help